# How to do a hypothesis testing for smoothing spline at x=certain value?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, multiple-comparisons, splines, cubic

I have a dataset with response variable y (e.g Starch content) and independent variable x (e.g. Size of Load) and used smoothing cubic splines to fit the data. The data is binned by a categorical variable (e.g. Method). So the number of spline lines will correspond to the number of countries being compared.

The scenario is like this. We want to know if 3 different methods will result to significant Starch content differences. However, the Starch content is dependent on Size of Load too. Our target is 250lbs but we cannot really control this. So what I do is plot the Starch content vs Size of Load to remove the effect of size of load. Then do spline fitting per Method (see image below). The goal is to answer if at Target=250 lbs, will there be significant differences in the starch content among each method?
[image]

Comment: If you don't have any interaction between country and age, this is completely standard and the fact that you're splining age is irrelevant: test the differences between the country coefficients as always.

Comment: Hi @whuber thanks for the reply. I edited the question and revised the example for clarity. For our problem, we needed to consider the x axis value (which is our specs target) to get fair comparison for each method. I could add confidence intervals per spline but I wonder if there is more rigorous hypothesis testing for it.

Comment: Have you considered using a GAM? I don't know if that is the case, since I don't know you application, but your splines might be a overfitting. If you work in R, mgcv could help you as well with finding a decent smoothing parameter.

Comment: Hi @Raphael, I don't know what GAM is—Let me do a bit of reading. For the splines overfitting, no worries, this is just a toy dataset. For actual data, we will optimize the lambda. For info, this graph was done via SAS JMP.

Comment: Would it be correct to interpret your example as representing the results of *three separate* regressions, one for each of the three response variables?  If so, the answer depends on whether you can assume the responses are conditionally independent.  If they are unlikely to be independent, you need a multivariate model for the correlations.  Otherwise, there are simple solutions along the lines I gave earlier.